# Does not return maximum and minimum frequency in lscpu

Tags: frequency

I wanted to find out my computer's CPU frequency I only get CPU MHz:1800.002 BogoMIPS:3600.00.Why not showing minimum and maximum frequency?

Comment: try `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_cur_freq` for your current frequency; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq` for your current system maximum cpu frequency configuration; `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_min_freq` for your current system minimum cpu frequency configuration; ... But I do not know why lscpu doesn't list them, unless if you aren't even using CPU frequency scaling. What CPU make and model?